# Change site level configuration in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, tomcat7

I have build a rest service in Java. For that there is a configuration file that I have to place in `/home/user1/` where user1 in the one where tomcat is running. If I change the path and move it to the `/home/user1/workspace/myRest/` (it is eclipse workspace where I build project)  then tomcat gave exception that file not found.

How do I inform tomcat that where you should look for the configuration file ? This file is being accessed by a jar in my project.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a system varible when starting tomcat. and access it from your library.

for example inside your catalina.bat(on windows)/setenv.sh(linux)

windows

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dconfig.path=%CATALINA_HOME%/{path to conf file}
```

linux

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dconfig.path=$CATALINA_HOME/{path to conf file}"
```

then access it from your code

```
 System.getProperty("config.path")
```